# How to fix my video lag that occurs on every possible video source on my Dell XPS13 9350 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, video-playback

I have a video issue: Whenever I play video, no matter the source (youtube, netflix, netflix app, a downloaded video file), the video lags the audio. This seems to build up as I play a video: it gets worse and is very apparent within minutes or even within the minute. Pausing the video sometimes seems to 'reset' the problem, but it will very soon be very obvious again. I am working on a Dell XPS13 9350 (2015), and Windows 10 Home. Knowing nearly nothing about such issues, my guess is that this is a graphics-related issue. The problem has been around for a few months now and a few weeks ago I had a graphics-driver update. I hoped this would solve the problem, but it didn't. I know this laptop doesn't have the best graphics-specs, but I can't imagine it is just not capable (anymore) of properly playing video? What could be the problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: The XPS 9350 is equipped with an [Intel 520 graphics](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-HD-Graphics-520.149940.0.html) chip. The chip shares the system RAM, lacking a dedicated memory. Despite this, the Intel HD Graphics 520 shouldn't have problems playing videos even at a high resolution, unless such playback occurs simultaneously with the use of applications that require a lot of RAM

Comment: Thanks for that insight. It happens always, whether I have, for example, Google Chrome open with many tabs, or nothing else (just a video player or for example the Netflix app). I'm aware that memory and graphics are shared, but I also figured it still shouldn't be a problem to properly play video. It has worked fine for years, but since a few months, there's this problem.

Comment: Chrome is a well-known RAM eater, so when playing videos it's better not to have more than two or three Chrome tabs open. You should also know which programs start with Windows and remain open in the system tray, because each of them uses some RAM. Check them in Task Manager > Startup and disable those that are not absolutely essential